# How to display data from a .NET Controller to React view?

Tags: javascript, c#, reactjs, asp.net-core

I am trying to learn how to use .NET and React and make a single page application where the React front end speaks to the .NET back end. I have decided to create a simple thermostat application where the user can view a thermostat temperature and press buttons which will increase and decrease that temperature. Before I even get that far though I am struggling to get the data from my Controller class to display on my front end. Here is my code:

ThermostatController.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace ThermostatDotNet.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class ThermostatController : Controller
    {

        private int _Temperature { get; set; }

        public ThermostatController(int _temperature)
        {
            _Temperature = _temperature;
        }

        [HttpGet, Route("GetTemp")]
        public int GetTemp()
        {
            return _Temperature;
        }

        [HttpGet, Route("Increase")]
        public int Increase()
        {
            _Temperature += 1;
            return _Temperature;
        }
    }
}
```

Thermostat.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export class Thermostat extends Component {
    state = {
        temp: ""
    }

    displayTemp() {
        fetch("api/Thermostat/GetTemp")
            .then(response => response.text())
            .then(data => {
                this.setState({ temp: data });

            });
    }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Thermostat</h1>
            <p>The temperature is:{this.state.temp}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The problem I am having is that I want to display the current temperature of the Thermostat when the user visits the application. I am not sure how to create that new thermostat and display the temperature in my React code? I have looked at other Stack Overflow answers but am still finding it difficult to implement here (I'm very new to React and .NET). Can anyone help? Thank you :)

**UPDATE**
After receiving the following error `InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'System.Int32' while attempting to activate 'ThermostatDotNet.Controllers.ThermostatController'.` I managed to fix this by using an interface and implementing this:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class ThermostatController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ITemperature _temperature;

        private int _Temperature { get; set; }

        public ThermostatController(ITemperature temperature)
        {
            _temperature = temperature;
        }

        [HttpGet, Route("GetTemp")]
        public int GetTemp()
        {
            return _Temperature;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to return number from your controller like this.

Using `return Ok();`

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class ThermostatController : Controller
    {
        public ThermostatController()
        {
        }

        [HttpGet, Route("GetTemp")]
        public int GetTemp()
        {
            return Ok(1);
        }
    }
```

Update: Then in your react use `componentDidMount` make sure you console.log(data) to see the data then use `data.something` to display data

```
componentDidMount() {
        fetch("api/Thermostat/GetTemp")
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data);
                this.setState({ temp: data });
        });
    }
```

You can read a document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Comment: Thank you for your help @TonyNgo - This actually gave me a different error however: `×
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Response]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`

Comment: Can you console.log the data to see if there any response ?

Comment: That react error probably means you are trying to display an object in the `p` tag. Maybe log the `temp` state property in your `render` function and see what it gives you.

Comment: Thanks @Nnanyielugo and @TonyNgo - I was receiving the same errors and then received this error: `InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'System.Int32' while attempting to activate 'ThermostatDotNet.Controllers.ThermostatController'.` After some googling I have managed to fix it (and have updated my question) :) Thanks for your help